# How do I install themes for Gnome3 in Debian 7?

Tags: debian, gnome, themes

I am trying to install the viva theme for my Debian install. I am having some issues. I am told to use the gnome tweak tool to select the theme. When I run the gnome tweak tool there is a yellow exclamation mark next to the theme selector portion. Through googling i've been told i'm missing extensions. When I try to add repo's detailed by various sources, then install the extensions mentioned, I am greeted with package not found messages.

This is the theme i'm interested in-

http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/viva+3.10?content=156545

One of the troubles i'm having is alot of the posts I find in google refer to Ubuntu and i'm not quite sure that applies to my ditro. Not sure if that is having an effect or not.

I've tried these solutions,

https://askubuntu.com/questions/72042/how-can-i-enable-themes-in-gnome-shell

No dice, package not found and the .deb files don't install, it says there were errors but it doesn't give me anymore information, the .deb files are also for ubuntu it would appear so that can't help.

Any advice and pointers to the right info is greatly appreciated! I am new to tweaking gnome and whatnot so i'm not quite sure what to do, keep running into the same walls.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out! It turns out I wasn't even running in Gnome 3, but Gnome Fall Back because my video driver had not been properly installed! I installed my video driver, rebooted and then I was properly running Gnome with all of the correct options/setting available for changing. Hope this helps anyone who stumbles across!

Answer (score 0):

[To install gnome on debian 7 wheezy](http://namhuy.net/1085/install-gui-on-debian-7-wheezy.html)

```
# apt-get install aptitude tasksel
```

Install gnome on debian

```
# tasksel install gnome-desktop --new-install
```